# How can I implement a pull-based system using Tokio?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to implement a pull-based system between a server and a client where the server will only push data when the client asks for it.

I was playing with Tokio and was able to create a push-based system where I was able to push a string at an interval of 1ms.

```
let done = listener
    .incoming()
    .for_each(move |socket| {
        let server_queue = _cqueue.clone();
        let (reader, mut writer) = socket.split();
        let sender = Interval::new_interval(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1))
            .for_each(move |_| {
                writer
                    .poll_write(server_queue.pull().borrow())
                    .map_err(|_| {
                        tokio::timer::Error::shutdown();
                    })
                    .unwrap();
                return Ok(());
            })
            .map_err(|e| println!("{}", e));
        ;
        tokio::spawn(sender);
        return Ok(());
    })
    .map_err(|e| println!("Future_error {}", e));
```

Is there a way to send only when the client asks for it without having to use a reader?

Comment: How do you propose that your client "asks for it"?

Comment: @Shepmaster I was just wondering if there was an existing library that can be used to handle this "neatly".

Comment: @VikasShetty Edited my answer with some plumbing to make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think back for a moment on the kind of events that could lead to this "sending of data". You can think of multiple ways:

- The client connects to the server. By contract, this is "asking for data". You've implemented this case
- The client sends an in-band message on the socket/pipe connecting the client and server. For that, you need to take the `AsyncRead` part of your `socket`, the `AsyncWrite` part that you've already used and build a duplex channel so you can read and talk at the same time
- The client sends an out-of-band message, typically on another proto-host-port triplet and using a different protocol. Your current server recognizes it, and sends the client that data. To do this, you need a reader for the other triplet, and you need a messaging structure in place to relay this to the one place having access to the `AsyncWrite` part of your socket

The short answer is no, you cannot really act on an event that you're not listening for.

---

> @Shepmaster I was just wondering if there was an existing library that can be used to handle this "neatly"

There is, and then there isn't.

Most libraries are centered around a specific problem. In your case, you've opted to work at the lowest possible level by having a TCP socket (implementing `AsyncRead + AsyncWrite`).

To do anything, you're going to need to decide on:

1. A transport format
2. A protocol

I tend to wrap code into this when I need a quick and dirty implementation of a duplex stream:

```
use futures::sync::mpsc::{UnboundedSender, unbounded};
use std::sync::{Arc};
use futures::{Sink, Stream, Future, future, stream};
use tokio::io::{AsyncRead, AsyncWrite};
use tokio::codec::{Framed, Encoder, Decoder};
use std::io;
use std::fmt::Debug;
use futures_locks::{RwLock as FutLock};

enum Message<T:Send+Debug+'static> {
    Content(T),
    Done
}

impl<T: Send + Debug + 'static> From<T> for Message<T> {
    fn from(message:T) -> Message<T> {
        Message::Content(message)
    }
}

struct DuplexStream<T:Send+Debug+'static> {
    writer: Arc<FutLock<UnboundedSender<Message<T>>>>,
    handlers: Arc<FutLock<Option<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Message<T>, Error = ()> + Send>>>>
}

impl<T:Send+Debug+'static> DuplexStream<T> {

    pub fn from<R,U>(framed_socket: Framed<R, U>) -> Arc<DuplexStream<T>>
        where U: Send + Encoder<Item = T> + Decoder<Item = T> + 'static, R: Send + AsyncRead + AsyncWrite + 'static {

        let (tx, rx) = framed_socket.split();

        // Assemble the combined upstream stream
        let (upstream_tx, upstream_rx) = unbounded();
        let upstream = upstream_rx.take_while(|item| match item {
            Message::Done => future::ok(false),
            _ => future::ok(true)
        }).fold(tx, |o, m| {
            o.send(match m {
                Message::Content(i) => i,
                _ => unreachable!()
            }).map_err(|_| {
                ()
            })
        }).map(|e| {
            Message::Done
        }).into_stream();

        // Assemble the downstream stream
        let downstream = rx.map_err(|_| ()).map(|r| {
            Message::Content(r)
        }).chain(stream::once(Ok(Message::Done)));

        Arc::new(DuplexStream {
            writer: Arc::new(FutLock::new(upstream_tx)),
            handlers: Arc::new(FutLock::new(Some(Box::new(upstream.select(downstream).take_while(|m| match m {
                Message::Content(_) => {
                    future::ok(true)
                },
                Message::Done => {
                    future::ok(false)
                }
            })))))
        })
    }

    pub fn start(self: Arc<Self>) -> Box<dyn Stream<Item = T, Error = io::Error> + Send> {
        Box::new(self.handlers
            .write()
            .map_err(|_| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::NotFound, "Stream closed"))
            .map(|mut handler| -> Box<dyn Stream<Item = T, Error = io::Error> + Send> {
                match handler.take() {
                    Some(e) => Box::new(e.map(|r| match r {
                        Message::Content(i) => i,
                        _ => unreachable!()
                    }).map_err(|_| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::NotFound, "Stream closed"))),
                    None => Box::new(stream::once(Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::AddrInUse, "Handler already taken"))))
                }
            }).into_stream().flatten()
        )
    }

    pub fn close(self: Arc<Self>) -> Box<dyn Future<Item = (), Error = io::Error> + Send> {
        self.inner_send(Message::Done)
    }
    pub fn send(self: Arc<Self>, message: T) -> Box<dyn Future<Item = (), Error = io::Error> + Send> {
        self.inner_send(message.into())
    }
    pub fn inner_send(self: Arc<Self>, message: Message<T>) -> Box<dyn Future<Item = (), Error = io::Error> + Send> {
        Box::new(self.writer.write()
            .map_err(|_| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::NotFound, "The mutex has disappeared")).and_then(|guard| {
                future::result(guard.unbounded_send(message).map_err(|_| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::BrokenPipe, "The sink has gone away")))
        }))
    }
}
```

This struct has a multitude of advantages, but a few drawbacks. The main advantage is that you can deal with the read and write part *on the same object* the same way you would in another language. The object itself implements `Clone` (since it's an `Arc`), every method is usable everywhere (particularly useful for old `futures` code) and as long as you keep a copy of it *somewhere* and don't call `close()` it'll keep running (as long as the underlying `AsyncRead + AsyncWrite` implementation is still there).

This does not absolve you from points 1 and 2, but you can (and should) leverage `tokio::codec::Framed` for point 1, and implement point 2 as business logic.

An example (it's actually a test ;-) ) of the usage:

```
#[test]
fn it_writes() {
    let stream = DuplexStream::from(make_w());
    let stream_write = Arc::clone(&stream);
    let stream_read=  Arc::clone(&stream);
    let dup = Arc::clone(&stream);
    tokio::run(lazy(move || {
        let stream_write = Arc::clone(&stream_write);
        stream_read.start().and_then(move |i| {
            let stream_write = Arc::clone(&stream_write);
            stream_write.send("foo".to_string()).map(|_| i)
        }).collect().map(|r| {
            assert_eq!(r, vec!["foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string(), "bazfoo".to_string(), "foo".to_string()])
        }).map_err(|_| {
            assert_eq!(true, false);
        })
    }));
}
```